# MySQL - IN subqueries does not work properly with INT 000

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a problem with the MySQL request below:

```
    SELECT u.id 
    FROM users u
    WHERE users.job_id IN ( SELECT id FROM jobs )
```

Where my 2 tables are like this:

users

```
id     | job_id
------ | ------
1      | 000350
2      | 000600
3      | 000000
```

jobs

```
id       | job
-------  | ---------
000350   | engineer 
000600   | sales
```

The result of my request is:

```
id  
----
1   
2    
3
```

The job_id 000000 (its a INT with six zeros) is not excluded from my results. But I don't want this line id = 3 and job_id = 000000.

Any idea ? Might it be a settings of mysql ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What are the types of the `job_id` columns in the two tables?

Comment: Note that there is no notion of an integer in MySQL having prefixed zeroes, nor does zero consist of six zeroes.  I feel your current problem could have been avoided by better table design.

Comment: Wierd the subquery `SELECT id FROM jobs` only should hold the result id off `000350` and `000600` the final result should be `1` and `2`

Answer (score 0):

Use a JOIN to get the results:

```
SELECT u.id 
    FROM users u
    JOIN jobs j
    ON u.job_id = j.id
```